# ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders(RepositoryFactory.class) return different between in source code and in jar

Tags: java, java-7, jackrabbit

Here is my code:

```
    Iterator iterator = ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders(RepositoryFactory.class);
    int i =0;
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        i++;
        System.out.println(iterator.next()+"---"+i);
    }
```

The `RepositoryFactory`'s implement instantiates are[image]
In source code,The above code print

```
    org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.RmiRepositoryFactory@735f7ae5---1
    org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JndiRepositoryFactory@614c5515---2
    org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryFactoryImpl@6df97b55---3
    org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2dav.Jcr2davRepositoryFactory@3dd3bcd---4
    org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.Jcr2spiRepositoryFactory@9629756---5
```

But in jar it just print

`org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.RmiRepositoryFactory@735f7ae5---1`

Here is the directory of my jar[image]

What should I do?